# curious why a question was deleted

Tags: discussion

a moderator has deleted a question of mine in regards to ftp access. Just curious why this would happen and/or how one can make sure quesions aren't deleted

https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/235184/what-folder-of-the-linux-server-is-the-folder-you-see-when-login-in-via-ftp?noredirect=1#comment327466_235184

can someone (maybe Marius who has deleted it) educate us on this practice?

Answer (score 1):

Your question was deleted because it has nothing to do with Magento from the coding or using points of view.

Comment: hm, I am trying to administrate Magento via ftp and my question was in regards to that usage. So I guess we disagree that is has _"nothing to do with Magento from using or coding pow"_ as you say. Anyway, can you recommend a more suitable location for such a question?

Comment: you can try on https://serverfault.com/ or stackoverflow.com

Comment: ok, thanks. Let's hope they won't reject it as a "Magento question" :-)

Comment: If it gets rejected, you can try again here, offering more details about what you are trying to achieve and how it is related to magento. Explain the problem not how you are trying to solve it. Or both.

Comment: hm, couldn't you have claimed this in comments of that quetion instead of just deleting it? I mean we use your and my time now with something that could have lead to valuable content for anyone in a susbstitue discussion here instead of solving the quesion. how about u 'undelete' it and I submit more context?

Comment: @user69143 your question is no where related to magento, just because your directory contain magento code , you cannot ask anything here